# Get original order of bulk loaded file in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get original order of bulk loaded file? The file does not have a sort column inside.

```
Bulk insert [dbo].[temp]
from 'C:\CSV\MyFile.csv' 
with ( 
    fieldterminator =';'
    ,rowterminator='\n'
    ,FIRSTROW=2
    ,CODEPAGE ='ACP')
```

I try to achieve goal by using:

```
select 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select 1)) AS RowNumber_approach1
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by %%physloc%%) AS RowNumber_approach2
from dbo.tb
```

and I get different results. Which, if any, approach should be ok? Is there any other method I should do it?

Comment: If you don't have a sort column in the file, I'm afraid it can't be done.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have presented two approaches in my question. Are you sure that neither of them works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. https://sqlblog.org/2008/12/16/sql-server-does-not-care-about-the-order-of-your-bulk-file

The only way is to include in original file the index column and then bulk load it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add an Identity(int) field to your import structure.  This should maintain the original load order.

Comment: Are you sure that the identity column will maintain the same order as file? How do you know that bulk insert does not shuffle the cards?

Comment: Yes,  I used to have a horrible multi-row structure,  This was the only way I could maintain the integrity

Comment: How do you do it then? I added `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp](
[Auto_increment] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,` ... but I get an error: `Bulk load data conversion error (truncation)` Bulk load seems not to work then. Should I modify the bulk load code to specify that identity column should be left "empty".

Comment: Add the identity as the last field of your import structure

Comment: If i add identity as the last column then I get the error `Msg 4864 Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 30 (Auto_increment).`

Comment: Give me a moment and I will post a sample

Comment: Identity may not fix it. I just found this https://sqlblog.org/2008/12/16/sql-server-does-not-care-about-the-order-of-your-bulk-file

Comment: Interesting.  It worked for me, otherwise we couldn't balance to the General Ledger

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, you were lucky. The order in which `IDENTITY` values are generated is guaranteed only if you have `ORDER BY` clause in your `INSERT` statement. In any case, most likely this is relevant only for normal `INSERT`, not for `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov You guys have me doubting gravity now.  I'm running some tests on my end to see if I can break the sequence.  So far, it is holding true.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov on a sample data-set of 5,000 rows, I can't get the process to fail (dozens of attempts).  However, when I bump it up to 30,000 rows, it fails at least 3 out of 15 runs.   So, you were right, I was lucky, this is not a valid methodology.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, a while ago I came across [Ordering guarantees in SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2005/07/20/ordering-guarantees-in-sql-server/), you may find it useful. In general, if you need a certain order, you need to use `ORDER BY`, otherwise the ordering is not defined.